# Image viewer that allows printing more than 100%

Tags: software-recommendation, printing

Eye of gnome can print images at different sizes than original, but it can't go more than 100%. I was wondering if there was any image program that could print more than 100% (namely, page size.) Also, it should support svgs (so no interpolation is required.) Gimp doesn't work, because you have to know the size in advance so it can rasterize it.

Answer (score 2):

Shotwell will print to page size.

[image: ShotwellPageSize]

Comment: i think you are correct geek

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't support `svg` format.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any svg format images to test with. Maybe someone else can chime in with a better answer

Comment: There are a number of conversion programs available that would allow you to convert svg to a format compatible with shotwell for printing purposes. I count no less than 7 online. What is the source of these SVG files?

Comment: https://answers.launchpad.net/inkscape/+question/38438 might also prove useful to you.